# Problems installing R base

Tags: r

I keep getting this error when trying to install R

```
sudo apt-get install r-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.2.0-3trusty) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 3.2.0-3trusty) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any one knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing all at once

```
 sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-core r-recommended r-base-html
```

but from your description is not clear how you manage to get into this situation in the first place.  This should not happen under normal use.